# msgget unable to join the mq

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, message-queue

I am using SysV for sending/receiving messages.

Inside the thread function of my Server class is where I create the key and MQ. This is done successfully and the mqID of the new MQ is stored in a char[] variable called mtext in a struct msgbuf

```
struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[100];
};
```

This is how I create the mqID in the thread function of the server class:

```
void *thread_function(void *arg){
    int temp; //temp placement for current client
    temp=i;
    key_t keyT;
    struct msgbuf bufT;
    keyT=ftok("mcs1.c", 'B'); //create key for client[temp]
    if ((client[temp].mqID=msgget(keyT, 0666 | IPC_CREAT))==-1){ //private mq for client[temp]
            perror("msgget");
    }
    bufT.mtype=2;   //1. SET MTYPE TO 2
    sprintf(bufT.mtext, "%d\n", client[temp].mqID);//2. SET MTEXT TO MQID OF PRIVATE MQ

    if (msgsnd(msqid, &bufT, sizeof(bufT.mtext),0)==-1) {perror("msgsnd");} //3. SEND TO CLIENT using global MQ

    ...
    }
```

The MQID of the new MQ i just created is stored in bufT

In the client class, This is how I rcv the MQID and create the MQ:

```
...
if(msgrcv(msqid, &buf, sizeof(buf.mtext), 2, 0) == -1){ //RECEIVE ACK MSG
            perror("msgrcv");
    }
    else{
            printf("ack received\n");
    }
    key_t key1;
    key1=atoi(buf.mtext);
    if ((mqT=msgget(key1, 0666)) == -1){
            printf("UNABLE TO JOIN PRIVATE MQ");
                    perror("msgget");
                    printf("%d", key1);
    }
...
```

Whenever I run the server and then a client, it says `msgget: No such file or directory` on the terminal running the client program.
Even though when I print the key in the client class and is the correct key, it still can't join the MQ. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake. 
Instead of

`sprintf(bufT.mtext, "%d\n", client[temp].mqID);`

it should be

`sprintf(bufT.mtext, "%d\n", keyT);`

Was trying to join a MQ with a MQID instead of a key.

Answer (score 0):

No such file or directory error occurs when a file name is specified and the file should exist but does not, or when one of the directories in a path name does not exist. It occurs with msgget() when key does not refer to any object and the IPC_CREAT flag is not set.

Comment: But I use `ipcs` to test if the Server creates the MQ and it does, the client just refuses to join the already made MQ

Comment: Access permissions on client and server side?